# Change background with button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks on a restyle button it will change the background to the images stored in my folder. I have a couple, and then you can choose to reset back to the normal image, however for some reason I cant get it to work, any help would be great on this matter:

**HTML buttons**

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeLook()">ReStyle</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeBack()">Reset</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
var counter = 0; 
function changeLook(){
    counter += 1;
    switch (counter) {
        case 1:
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "../Image/BackgroundImage2.jpg";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "../Image/BackgroundImage3.jpg";
            break;
        case 3:
            counter = 0;
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "../Image/BackgroundImage4.jpg";
            break;
    }
}

function changeBack(){
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "../Image/BackgroundImage1.jpg";
}
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding-top: 23px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: url('../Image/BackgroundImage1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `../` in the JavaScript image paths.

Comment: What does your project's directory structure look like?

Comment: hmm i dunno, simply dose not work, i have the right dicerct, also no errors etc , its really weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `url(`*image path*`)` like:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../Image/BackgroundImage2.jpg)";
```

---

```js
var counter =0; 
function changeLook() {
    counter += 1;

    switch (counter) {
        case 1:
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://placehold.it/200x200)";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://placehold.it/300x300)";
            break;
        case 3:
            counter = 0;
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://placehold.it/400x400)";
            break;          
    }
}

function changeBack(){
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://placehold.it/200x200)";
}
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 23px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/200x200') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="changeLook()">ReStyle</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeBack()">Reset</a>
```

Comment: Hmm this actually got me closer to the correct answer, but now the background goes grey

Comment: I just mean the background it self, goes grrey, so no background at all

Comment: Ok got it to work , for some resaon i dont need to use ../ but the file path u have to go back anyway thanks xx

Comment: Just missing the ../

Comment: @Nevershow2016 nevermind ! glad to help you, _Thanks_

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely could use your current code. If it isn't working, then the issue is likely that your relative paths within your CSS files for your `background` properties are incorrect.

It's important to remember that **the paths used within a CSS file will be relative to the CSS file itself and not where it is referenced**. However, when you use the relative references in your Javascript code, it will be made relative to where the Javascript is referenced (i.e. your HTML document).

You may want to consider defining CSS styles to handle these changes :

```
body.background1 {
     background: url('../Images/Image1.jpg');
}
body.background2 {
     background: url('../Images/Image2.jpg');
}
/* Continue as necessary */
```

And then simply update the class for your `<body>` element using Javascript :

```
// Use the counter to determine which style to apply
switch (counter) {
    case 1:
        document.body.className = "background1";
        break;
    case 2:
        document.body.className = "background2";
        break;
    case 3:
        counter = 0;
        document.body.className = "background3";
        break;          
}
```

**Example**

You can [see a very basic example of this here](http://jsbin.com/dokeda/edit?html,css,js,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: _"it will be made relative to where the Javascript is defined"_ - I think you meant _relative to the **HTML document**_

Comment: Yes, I suppose I meant referenced instead of defined (as the Javascript would be referenced from the HTML document and relative to it). I've updated the verbiage.

Comment: Ah thanks for the feedback, i tried this but it does not seem to work is well , its really weird

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you're referencing your file paths incorrectly. Check your developer console within your browser. Do you see any 404 errors?

Additionally, you can simplify your `changeLook` function by using a modulus:

```
var counter = 1; 
function changeLook(){
   counter = counter % 4 + 1;
   document.body.style.backgroundImage = "../Image/BackgroundImage" + counter + ".jpg";
}

function changeBack() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "../Image/BackgroundImage1.jpg";
}
```